# Can't add reference to PCANBasic.dll or CANdo.dll in Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am trying to create a user interface where I can control and receive information from an electronic actuator through a CAN bus.

I am a relatively new programmer with experience in MATLAB and VBA, and have no experience with communicating to external devices.

I downloaded a couple of dll files look like they would be helpful, but when I try to reference either of them I get this error message: "A reference to (name and location of DLL) could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

I have tried relocating the file to the project directory and under C:\Windows\System32.  I've looked over the documentation for the DLLs, spoken with customer support for the companies that supplied them, and talked to our IT department but still haven't found any hints.

Any idea on how to get these working? Or is there any built in funtionality in Visual Basic 2010 Express that would allow me to communicate with the CAN bus instead.

Comment: Can you detail exactly how you are adding a reference to them?

Comment: I opened up a new project ( a Windows Forms Application) and then wen to Project ->Add Reference->Browse and then chose the dll file which was located under C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: Do you know if the DLL file matches the bit of your program/computer? I.e. is x86 for a x86 program? Typically that is the message you get for that problem.

Comment: It's a 64 bit dll and I'm using a 64 bit operating system. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You may have a 64 bit OS, but make sure your project settings have the build to match a 64 dll (check your target CPU settings). You can create a x86 program on a x64 computer. But again, this isn't the only problem that returns this error, just a common one.

Comment: I went to the solutions explorer->properties->compile and the platform says Active (x86), so it sounds like that may have been the problem, but it won't let me change this since I have the express version. I just tried using the 32 bit version of the dll and still had no luck.